# Why we don't have 'const iterator' in the C++ standard, but const_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, std

Why was a special type `const_iterator` introduced?

Why not make some of the iterator internals mutable, and go with standard C++ `const iterator`?

Was `const iterator` ever discussed?

Comment: Would you expect `iter++` to be allowed on a `const iterator`?

Comment: Because `const iterator` means iterator that cannot be changed, not iterator that disallows changing data it refers to.

Comment: This essentially comes down to the difference between `T * const` and `T const*`. A `const iterator` wouldn't allow mutating the iterator, but you could freely modify the iteree (is that even a valid word?), while a `const_iterator` allows mutating the iterator but not the iteree.

Comment: Consider the difference between `int*`, `int* const`, `int const*` (i.e. `iterator`, `iterator const`, and `const_iterator` for a `std::array<int, N>`). Do you understand why the difference is required?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, I would. In a sense, iterator is generalization of the pointer, and I could do `const float* cf = ...; ++cf`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux good, now let's say you have type alias `using floatptr = float *;` try to make it pointer to const data only using `floatptr` alias

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Then the problem is that `const iterator` is analogous to `float * const cf`, not `const float * cf`. You can't express the first use of `const` by just applying `const` to pointer-like objects, it only expresses the second use. If you write your pointer-like object such that it's constness expresses both meaning then you cannot distinguish between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `iterator` is conceptualy a location on a linear space. At each position in this space is located an object.

`const iterator`s do exist. This an iterator that always point to the same location. You cannot do `i++` for example. Even if you can not change the pointed location, you can change the object stored at that location: `*i=10` for example

A `const_iterator` should be read iterator to const...: this is the opposite of a `const iterator`, you can change the pointed location, performing `i++` is alowed, but you can never change the pointed value: `*i=10` not allowed.

So you have 4 versions: iterator, const iterator, const_iterator, and const const_iterator!

Answer (score 3):

As pointer is a special case for iterator let's look on this example:

```
using float_ptr = float *;
float f = 0;
const float_ptr ptr = &f;
*ptr = 1.0; // fine changes variable f
ptr = nullptr; // fails, ptr is const
```

What happened? We have constant pointer to non-const data. But we need non-const pointer to const data. Obvious solution is:

```
using const_float_ptr = const float *;
```

here it is additional `const_iterator` type. Problem for iterators in general is the same: `const iterator` would have different meaning than `const_iterator` and on top of that returning const object **by value** is practically useless in C++ as you cannot enforce it to be assigned only to const object.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are just Pointers, with some of their messy details abstracted away, and with the potential to have Debug information inserted if the compiler is permitted to insert such symbols.

As a result, it's important to think about the different ways that CV-qualifiers can be applied to Pointers, and how those ways differ from how we handle direct values.

For example, in C++, the following type declarations are NOT equivalent:

```
//Gonna leak lots of memory, don't worry about that for now
int * ptr = new int(1);
*ptr = 2;
ptr = new int(3);

int const* ptr2 = new int(4);
//*ptr2 = 5;//Not permitted, is a pointer-to-const, meaning the data it points to is immutable
ptr2 = new int(6);
ptr2 = ptr;
*ptr = 4;
//*ptr2 = 5;//immutability of data is enforced by the alias, not by the underlying data.
//ptr can still modify its own data, but ptr2 may not, even if it's the same data.

int * const ptr3 = new int(7);
*ptr3 = 8;
//ptr3 = new int(9);//Not permitted, is a const-pointer, meaning the pointer itself is immutable
//Note that the data being pointed to is NOT immutable, and can be freely altered

int const* const ptr4 = new int(10);
//*ptr4 = 11;//Not permitted, data pointed to is immutable
ptr4 = new int(12);//Not permitted, pointer is immutable
```

In terms of C++ iterators, `const iterator` can be thought of as being equivalent to the `int * const ptr3` declaration I showed above: the data pointed at can be freely manipulated, but the pointer itself cannot be changed. `const_iterator`, conversely, is equivalent to `ptr2`, meaning the data cannot be modified, but the pointer can be made to point at something else. A hypothetical `const const_iterator` would be like `ptr4`, permitting neither the data to change nor the pointer itself to change.